# Equality involving ranks of matrices

Tags: matrices, matrix-rank

Let $A,B\in M_n(\mathbb{C})$ such that $A^2=B^2=I_n$. Prove that
$$\hbox{rank}~((A+I_n)(B-I_n))+\hbox{rank}~((A-I_n)(B+I_n))=\hbox{rank}~(A-B).$$
I have managed to prove the (easier) inequality (using the subadditivity property of the rank):
$$\hbox{rank}~((A+I_n)(B-I_n))+\hbox{rank}~((A-I_n)(B+I_n))=\hbox{rank}~((A+I_n)(B-I_n))+\hbox{rank}~(-(A-I_n)(B+I_n))=$$
$$=\hbox{rank}~(AB-A+B-I_n)+\hbox{rank}~(-AB-A+B+I_n))\geq \hbox{rank}~((AB-A+B-I_n)+(-AB-A+B+I_n))=$$
$$=\hbox{rank}~(-2(A-B))=\hbox{rank}~(A-B).$$

Comment: Where have you used the assumption $A^2 = B^2 = I$?

Comment: @HansEngler: Nowhere, yet. Perhaps it is used for the reverse inequality.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$A$ and $B$ are diagonalisable and their eigenvalues are $\pm1$. Hence
$$
A=P\pmatrix{I_r&0\\ 0&-I_{n-r}}P^{-1}
\ \text{ and }\ B=Q\pmatrix{I_s&0\\ 0&-I_{n-s}}Q^{-1}
$$
for some invertible matrices $P$ and $Q$ and for some integers $r$ and $s$. Let
$$
P^{-1}Q=\pmatrix{X&Y\\ Z&W}
$$
where $X$ is $r\times s$. Then
\begin{align}
(A+I)(B-I)&=P\pmatrix{0&-4Y\\ 0&0}Q^{-1},\\
(A-I)(B+I)&=P\pmatrix{0&0\\ -4Z&0}Q^{-1}.
\end{align}
It is now clear that
\begin{align}
&\operatorname{rank}\bigl((A+I)(B-I)\bigr)
+\operatorname{rank}\bigl((A-I)(B+I)\bigr)\\
=\ &\operatorname{rank}\bigl((A+I)(B-I)+(A-I)(B+I)\bigr).
\end{align}